# Append a directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, environment-variables

So, I have this batch file that supposedly appends my script to the path variable

```
@echo OFF

setx path "%path%;%cd%\script.py"
```

But I encounter a few problems.

1. Appending my script.py would cause the path to be greater than 1024 characters. Thus outputting a warning.

> WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

2. Using the code above copies the PATH from **system** PATH to the **user** PATH then tries to append script.py. (I have other directories in the **user** PATH that are not in the **system** PATH and using the script overwrites those.)

My question is, how do I overcome the 1024 character limitation?

And how can I properly append script.py to the **user** PATH without copying the ones from the  **system** PATH?

Example:

**Original**

> USER PATH: C:\dirA;...;C:\dirB;
>
> SYSTEM PATH: C:\dirC;...;C:\dirD;

After running the script...

**Expected**

> USER PATH: C:\dirA;...;C:\dirB;C:\something\script.py
>
> SYSTEM PATH: C:\dirC;...;C:\dirD;

**Actual**

> USER PATH: C:\dirC;...;C:\dirD;C:\somet (truncated to 1024 characters)
>
> SYSTEM PATH: C:\dirC;...;C:\dirD;

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Comment: @UnknownOctopus Yes. But it doesn't really work. :(

Answer (score 1):

Next script shows a possible approach.

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
rem  enabledelayedexpansion
echo adding "%~1" to the user level HKCU\Environment /v Path
call :showReg old
call set "expanded=%~1"
if "%expanded%"=="" goto :usage
if not exist "%expanded%\" goto :usage
set "HKCU_type=REG_EXPAND_SZ"
set "HKCU_path="
for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%F in ('
  reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path 2^>NUL ^|findstr /I "path"
  ') do (
    set "HKCU_path=%%H"
    REG ADD HKCU\Environment /v Path /t %HKCU_type% /d %%H;%~1 /f >NUL
  ) 
if not defined HKCU_path (
    REG ADD HKCU\Environment /v Path /t %HKCU_type% /d %~1 /f >NUL
)
:endlocal
call :showReg new
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:usage
  echo      directory "%~1" ^("%expanded%"^) not found
goto :endlocal

:showReg
<NUL set /P "=%~1: "
reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path 2>NUL|findstr /I "path"|findstr /V /R "^$"
if errorlevel 1 echo not defined
goto :eof
```

Provided examples show attempts to add

- a non existent directory `d:\FooBar` (rejected);
- an existent directory `d:\bat` (hard-coded reference);
- an existent directory `%SystemRoot%` (variable reference, hard-coded in the registry);
- an existent directory `^%windir^%` (variable reference keeps expandable in the registry).

**Output**:

```
==>31602391.bat d:\FooBar
adding "d:\FooBar" to the user level HKCU\Environment /v Path
old: not defined
     directory "d:\FooBar" ("d:\FooBar") not found
new: not defined

==>31602391.bat d:\test
adding "d:\test" to the user level HKCU\Environment /v Path
old: not defined
new:     Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\test

==>31602391.bat %SystemRoot%
adding "C:\Windows" to the user level HKCU\Environment /v Path
old:     Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\test
new:     Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\test;C:\Windows

==>31602391.bat ^%windir^%
adding "%windir%" to the user level HKCU\Environment /v Path
old:     Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\test;C:\Windows
new:     Path    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\test;C:\Windows;%windir%

==>
```

Comment: Folder paths with a space (very common) or an ampersand (rare) are not successfully added/appended to __user__ `PATH`. Also if __user__ `PATH` already exists with a folder path containing space or `&`, appending the passed folder path fails. Reason: Missing double quotes on the two `REG ADD` command lines around the data string. Additionally using `%~1` directly on `REG ADD` command lines could be critical on passed folder path ends with a backslash which escapes `"` (once added). So it is necessary to make sure the passed folder path does not end with ``\``.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/601015/how-to-update-the-path-user-environment-variable-from-command-line

```
@echo OFF


for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query HKCU\Environment /v PATH') do (
    if [%%b]==[] (
        setx PATH "%%~a;%cd%"
    ) else (
        setx PATH "%%~a %%~b;%cd%"
    )
)
```

Comment: This code does not work at all because of multiple reasons. If __user__ `PATH` does not exist in Windows registry, `reg query` just outputs an error message and `for` has nothing to process and so __user__ `PATH` is not defined with current directory path. If registry value `PATH` exists with an empty string, there is no third token and so `for` does again nothing. In other words the __user__ `PATH` must exist with at least one folder path to add the current directory at all. The batch file works also only on Windows Vista and later Windows versions, but not on Windows XP.

Comment: The code does not check if __user__ `PATH` already ends with a semicolon in which case appending current directory should be done without an additional semicolon. But the biggest problem with this code is a corruption of __user__ `PATH` if the string becomes longer than 1024 characters because of `setx` __truncates__ the string to 1024 characters with displaying an appropriate information before adding it to Windows registry. So it could happen that instead of appending current directory, the existing __user__ `PATH` is truncated (garbled) by this code.

Answer (score -3):

```
setx path c:\whatever
```

For `path` setx appends the path specified to the existing path. You don't specify the existing paths, only the new one. It also won't add a path twice.

Here's something I use

```
%windir%\system32\setx path %~sdp0 > "%temp%\filter.tmp"
```

The redirection hides error messages if I try and add twice. See the `call /?` command if you don't know what `%~sdp0` is

Comment: "setx path c:\whatever" actually overwrites the whole environment variable which is also bad for me

Comment: At first it looks like this is non-destructive, but it totally is. Watch out!

The %path% variable is the concatenation of the _machine_ and _user_ paths; the command in bill's answer replaces the _user_ path entirely.

Comment: setx modifies the path permanently, set modifies the current shell only.  This answer is misleading and potentially dangerous.